# How to not show code source from ctrl + u

Tags: html, css, xhtml, blogger

So I've surfing on the internet and I found cool sites. And when i want to clone his design, i can't see the source code by (ctrl+u).. It's not showing. How do I make it like them.

The sites-> [sources](http://view-source:https://www.dte.web.id/)

looks like i cannot click the link.. here's the raw `view-source:https://www.dte.web.id/`

Comment: viewed by 6 and no answer??

Comment: C O M M U N I T Y

Comment: You can see how it's built via developer tools.

Answer (score -1):

Using the code below, you will be disabling the function (ctrl + u). It is important to know that it does not prevent any user from viewing the source code through the "view-soure: link"

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
function testKeyCode(e) {
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e) keycode = e.which;
var e = e || window.event;
           if (e.ctrlKey &&
                  (e.keyCode === 67 ||
                   e.keyCode === 86 ||
                   e.keyCode === 85 ||
                   e.keyCode === 117)) {
    alert('This website is protected against attempts to clone. Your IP has been duly recorded on our server and if you persist it will be forwarded to the competent authorities');
   return false;
   } else {
    return true;
   }
}
document.onkeydown = testKeyCode;
</script>
```

Comment: As your code is client side, you can't hide anything.